# WP_Query, Taxonomy, list of attached items to a Term, sorted

Tags: taxonomy, sort

I have a Taxonomy, “Genre”.
“Genre” has a Term, “advert”.
I want my taxomomy template to grab all Custom Posts attached to that term, sort them by my last_name, first_name, short_title Custom Fields, and output.

But my custom query is returning 0 posts! I would love to get another set of eyes on this. I’m missing something!

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'terms'    => array( 'advert' )
        )
    ),
        'meta_query'      => array(
            'relation'           => 'AND',
            'last_name_clause'   => array(
                'key'     => 'last_name',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'first_name_clause'  => array(
                'key'     => 'first_name',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'short_title_clause' => array(
                'key'     => 'short_title',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby'        => array(
            'last_name_clause'   => 'ASC',
            'first_name_clause'  => 'ASC',
            'short_title_clause' => 'ASC',
        ),
    );
$newQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Best regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for custom posts, but don't define `post_type` in your query, which means it will default to the core `post` post type only.

You need to incorporate

`'post_type' => 'my-cpt'`

into your query.

Comment: So close!  I added 'post_type' => 'biblio' to my query, but it still results in 0 posts.  Thinking...

Comment: I also tried 'post_type' => 'any'.  Still no joy.

Comment: Must be something else wrong with my query.  This retreives "biblio" posts:  'post_type' => 'biblio',
 'posts_per_page' => 10